# PVC bridge IP address conflict

Tags: router, ip, adsl, adsl-router

ADSL Router. DHCP On.

PVC0:
8/35
PPPoE/LLC
IGMP: Disabled
NAT: On
Default Connection: Enabled (Internet)

PVC1:
0/33
Bridge

PVC3:
0/32
PPPoE/LLC
IGMP: Enabled
NAT: On
Default Connection: Disabled (IPTV)

Routing Host IP: 10.1.0.0/255.255.255.0

IP address conflict! Any ideas?

Comment: Your question does not list any IP addresses/ranges How can we help with an IP conflict without the relevant info?

Comment: Thank you @davidgo for your help. I applied the above settings to another router (different model) and no IP address conflict happens. To my knowledge DHCP is the one responsible for internal IP addresses. It's on configured to range 192.168.1.10 to 192.168.1.20 (10 devices only). When I connect any device, a conflict happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using virtual network (VLAN).

No more IP conflict.